# Angular 5 issue when routing in builded app

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 application when I try the built app I have some problem, If I navigate normally through pages it is ok, but if I reload a detail page it seems like fonts are not loaded ( I load all fonts from my assets folder because the app has to work without online dependencies).
And if I reload non detail page it works good, why?

**app.routing**

```
  {
    path: 'ticketBundles',
    loadChildren: './ticket-bundles/shared/ticket-bundle.module#TicketBundleModule',
    data: { roles: ['role.admin', 'role.backoffice'] }
  },
```

**ticketBundleRouting.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {TicketBundleListComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-list/ticket-bundle-list.component';
import {TicketBundleNewComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-new/ticket-bundle-new.component';
import {TicketBundleDetailComponent} from '../ticket-bundle-detail/ticket-bundle-detail.component';

const TicketBundleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TicketBundleListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: TicketBundleNewComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':code',
    component: TicketBundleDetailComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':code/copy',
    component: TicketBundleNewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(TicketBundleRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class TicketBundleRoutingModule { }
```

And in angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
                "app-styles.css",
                "./assets/css/fonts.css",
                .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in  of your index.html base path:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: already have it: `<body class="bootstrap-collapse">
 <base href='/'>
 <app-my-app>
  <div class="loader">
   <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
   </svg>
  </div>
 </app-my-app>
</body>`

Comment: Try to put between <head></head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
"styles": [... "./assets/css/fonts.css",
```

to

```
"styles": [... "/assets/css/fonts.css",
```

if that does not help, try to load your font in scss files.

styles.scss:

```
@font-face { font-family: "your font name"; src: url("/assets/source-of-font"); }

$globally-available-font-variable: "your font name";
```

in any component's scss:

```
@import './src/style.scss';

.somediv{
  font: $globally-available-font-variable
}
```